# Netsuite CASE in Customer search to return multiple lines

Tags: oracle, expression, case, netsuite

I have a simple Customer savedsearch in Oracle Netsuite which returns the following columns:

```
{partnercode}
{entityid}
```

I would like to write a CASE statement for the first column which return an extra line in the savedsearch when {additionalpartner}!=NULL. The value for that will be {additionalpartner.code}

Example of output sought:

```
AA 1
BA 1
AA 2
AA 3
```

...when customer '1' has {partnercode}='AA' and {additionalpartner}='BA' and customers '2' and '3' have {partnercode}='AA' and {additionalpartner}=NULL

Thanks and good day